# Border Bottom length in css

Tags: html, css

I am working on the footer section of a webpage. I am trying to limit the length of border bottom in css but unfortunately I am not able to restrict its length for some reasons. I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb9zaq22/) for it.

The length of border-bottom which I want excatly is shown in this [image](https://postimg.org/image/4em7u7ab1/).

The code which I have written in the fiddle are:

```
.footer p
{
  border-bottom: solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width (length) of your border will be exactly the width of your element. You can't set border to half of your element.

If you want to change lower the width of your border - lower the width of your element:

```
.footer p
{
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: solid black;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/74zgg81d/

Another option is to set a container for that `p` element with the desired width (and that `p` will use 100% of it's parent's width):

```
<div class="footer">
    <div style="width: 150px">
        <p>
            ADDITIONAL INFO
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Length issue is solved. One more last question, how can I reduce the width of the border ?

Comment: You can set it's width to 2px for example

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I just want to make the border less thick. Its very thick at this moment. Is there any way we can adjust the thickness of the border ?

Comment: I figured it out. Its border-bottom-width: 2px;